# Docker Swarm CE, Reverse-Proxy without shared config file on master nodes

Tags: reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I've been wrestling with this for several days now.  I have a swarm with 9 nodes, 3 managers.  I'm planning on deploying multiple testing environments to this swarm using Docker-Compose for each environment.  We have many rest services in each environment that I would like to manage access to them through a reverse proxy so that access to the services comes through a single port per environment.  Ideally I would like it do behave something like this `http://dockerNode:9001/ServiceA` and `http:/dockerNode:9001/ServiceB`.

I have been trying traefic, docker proxy, HAProxy, (I haven't tried NGINX yet).  All of these have ran into issues where I can't even get their examples to work, OR they require me to drop a file on each masternode, or setup cloud storage of some sort).

I would like to be able to have something just work by droping it into a docker-compose file, but I am also comfortable configuring all the mappings in the compose file (these are not dynamically changing environments where services come and go).

What is there a working example of this type of setup, or what should I be looking into?

Comment: you should update more detail of configuration in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your service using the server IP and the service port, then you need to setup `dnsrr endpoint mode` to override the docker swarm's service mesh. Here is a yaml so you know how to do it.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  alpine:
    image: alpine
    ports:
      - target: 9100
        published: 9100
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.host == node1
```

Note the configuration `endpoint_mode: dnsrr` and the way the port has been defined. Also note the `placement contraint` that will make the service only be able to be schedule in the with the label `node1`. Thus, now you can access your service using node1's IP address and port 9100. With respect to the URI `serviceA` just add it.